# How to boot from Live-USB?

Tags: boot, windows, live-usb

I've followed every step on: ["Create a USB stick on Windows"](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)  but after it says everything is succesful, I open Wubi, which is opened in arabic. I understand some of it, and continue to choose the button that tells me to restart now. after the computer restarts, it still opens in Windows XP.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've missed some points about booting your computer from an USB drive. To boot your computer from USB drive, there are mainly 2 steps.

1. Install your desired OS on the USB drive - To do this there are plenty of softwares like; [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), [USB Image Writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) etc.
2. Boot your computer with that USB drive - To do this you need to change your boot up options from BIOS. At first enter your bios setting by pressing DEL or F2. Change your **First bootable device** to your USB drive. Now insert your USB drive and reboot your computer.

Comment: thanks for the answer but before i do that, i'd like to know what would happen if i take off the USB? would the OS simply switch back to windows XP? because i'm only trying ubuntu currently, which is why i have it on a USB, and i wouldn't want to lose windows XP forever.

Comment: @user142814, obviously, your Windows XP will be there. You can use ubuntu numerous time with that USB drive, when you'll take off the USB, you Windows XP will be back in place.

Answer (score 1):

**Using your LiveCD**

Put the Ubuntu CD into the CD/DVD-drive and reboot the computer. You should see a menu with "Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer" at the top. If you don't get this menu, read the booting From the CD guide for more information. [Ubuntu Doc](http://tinyurl.com/22epmn)

When installing or trying the LiveCD version of Ubuntu from a DVD, your computer has to be able to boot from that DVD. Usually this consists of just inserting the disk into your DVD drive and rebooting your computer. Sometimes though this doesn't work, or just not as expected or planned. Here are some common problems and how to fix them.

**BIOS is not set to boot from CD or DVD drive**

This should be as simple as entering the BIOS, enable booting from the CD-ROM drive, and making sure that the CD-ROM is before the hard drive in the boot order.

The most common way to enter the BIOS is to press the DELETE key when the computer is first booted(this seems to be becoming standard). On other systems it could be a different key, or combination of keys like ESC, F1, F2, F10, F12, Ctrl-Esc, Alt-Esc, Ctrl-Alt-Esc, Ctrl-Alt-Enter, Ins or even others. You might have to press, press and hold, or press multiple times. The best way to find out the details of that is to look in the users manual or search the manufactures website. A few different Bios screens.

A common power-on BIOS screen(notice the 'press DEL for setup' message)
[image]

A typical BIOS boot menu screen
[image]

**PC requires you to hold down or press a key to boot from CD**

Some computers require you to hold down or press a key to enable booting from the CD drive, the best place to find this information is in your computers user manual or the manufactures website. Here are some common keys to try if you lack that information.

Apple Computers and others: Hold down the C key while rebooting. Toshiba, IBM and others: press F12 while booting to get to the boot menu and choose CD-ROM. Asus and others: press TAB key while booting and select CD-ROM from boot menu.

[image]

**CD/DVD drive can't boot in AHCI/Raid mode**

A large number of CD/DVD drives have problems running under AHCI/Raid mode (from not working at all to refusing to boot).

Either plug drive into another SATA port that isn't set to AHCI/Raid or if that can't be done go into BIOS and set mode of SATA ports to IDE/Compatibility mode.

(WARNING: if your Boot drive is plugged into same group of ports it may fail to boot after change(and obviously any Raid arrays will fail also)).

**Multiple CD/DVD drives in your computer**

Some computers will only allow booting from one CD or DVD drive even though you have 2 or more CD/DVD drives. So try the disk in each of the drives while rebooting the computer.

**BIOS does not have the option of booting from CD/DVD drive**

Some manufacturers provide BIOS updates that can correct this issue. For a BIOS update, please check with the manufacturer.

A workaround is available if you can read from your CD-ROM drive, but can not boot from it. You may be able to use the [SmartBootManager](http://tinyurl.com/22vzrn) on a floppy disk to force your computer to boot from the CD-ROM drive.

**CD drive not capable of booting a CD (older drives)**

Some drives are just too old and do not support booting and will require you to:

Purchase or borrow a newer CD-ROM drive.
Use the SmartBootManager to boot from the CD-ROM drive.

[Ubuntu Doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)

Comment: About the other question about cross-booting options please post another question specifically for that and I will gladly answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try unetbootin (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net). It works damn good and is a multi-platform software.

You don't need to open wubi btw. Just reboot using the usb-stick.